# DynamoDB: How to set FilterExpression for scan api where values in ExpressionAttributeValues depend on a result of some processing on multiple fields?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

So I want to scan the table and filter the result by the sum of values stored in 2 fields.

Currently my js code looks like this

```
var params = {
    TableName : "core-atv-quota-table-dev",
    FilterExpression: "#info.#branch = :branchId AND {{#info.#points / #info.#location}} > :score",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
         "#info": "matching_info",
         "#branch": "branch",
         "#points": "points",
         "#location": "location"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":branchId": "3",
        ":score": "8"
    },
    ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'TOTAL'
};
docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.error(err); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```

As you can see, `{{#points/#location}}` would not work. In this particular case, I can probably compute and store the value on insert and compare to that but in my use case I don't know which fields from `matching_info` will be used to filter the results.

I am looking for a way to get dynamodb to grab values from an item, process them (addition, subtraction etc) and use the processed info to match to a value given to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. `FilterExpression` doesn't allow for arithmetic operations.

> The syntax for a filter expression is identical to that of a condition
>   expression. Filter expressions can use the same comparators,
>   functions, and logical operators as a condition expression.

[FilterExpression Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression)

[Comparison Operator and Function Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html)